# Mysql syntax for a search engines with names

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a "search engine" with people in php. I have two columns. The first is with first_name and the secon is with last name i use this sql syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE first_name OR last_name LIKE '$search_term%'
```

I wand the sql to search for first name and for last name the same time with out having one column with first_name and last_name together. Please Help !!!!

Comment: (And many other questions, no idea how often this exact code and question came up. Try [our search function](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20search%20database%20first_name%20last_name%20LIKE)!)

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users 
WHERE  first_name LIKE '$search_term%' AND 
       last_name LIKE '$search_term%'
```

But the query above performs *full table scan* because *it doesn't use index*. For better performance, search about `FULL TEXT SEARCH`.

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks men worked! but when i am typing the first name (works) and then th last name doesn't work

Comment: and doesn't work means? do you want that searching must be true for both condition?

Comment: if that's the case, use `AND` not `OR` see my update

Comment: I think that i have to use this in my syntax GROUP CONCAT

Comment: why `GROUP_CONCAT` how does your records look like?

Comment: i have one column with first_name and one column with last_name

Comment: if the columns in just in a row, you need to use `CONCAT` not `GROUP_CONCAT`. eg `CONCAT(firstname, ' ', last_name) LIKE '$search_term%'`

Comment: thanks me your last example works as i want it thanks!